# C# Error: Object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, wpf

I need a little help here. I am trying to have the Latitude and Longitude values populate 2 `textboxes` in my WPF application. Now I can get the values to show up in a `MessageBox` all formatted the way I need it to appear in the text boxes.

However when I try to send the data to the textboxes I am getting

> "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Registration.tbXCoords'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//Registration.xaml.cs     

using System.Windows;
using System.Device.Location;
using System;

namespace Battle_Sample
{

public partial class Registration : Window
{
    public Registration()
    {
        WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        InitializeComponent();
        CLocation myLocation = new CLocation();
        myLocation.GetLocationEvent();
    }

    public class CLocation
    {
        GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher;

        public void GetLocationEvent()
        {
            this.watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
            this.watcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(watcher_PositionChanged);
            bool started = this.watcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
            if (!started)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("GeoCoordinateWatcher timed out on start.");
            }
        }

        public void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
        {
            PrintPosition(e.Position.Location.Latitude, e.Position.Location.Longitude);
        }

        public void PrintPosition(double Latitude, double Longitude)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("X: " + Latitude.ToString("0.00") + ", Y: " + Longitude.ToString("0.00"));

            //The following two lines are where I am getting the error
            tbXCoords.Text = (Latitude.ToString());
            tbYCoords.Text = (Longitude.ToString());
        }
    }
  }
}




//Registration.xaml

<Window x:Class="Battle_Sample.Registration"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Battle_Sample"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Battle Registration" Height="300" Width="300">

<Grid>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3">
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Location:" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,6,0,0" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3">
        <TextBlock Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center">X</TextBlock>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbXCoords" Margin="5" Width="50" IsEnabled="False" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3">
        <TextBlock Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Y</TextBlock>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbYCoords" Margin="5" Width="50" IsEnabled="False" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tbXCoords`and `tbYCoords`are fields defined in your `Registration` class and, as the error message is telling you, they are not static therefore in order to access them, you need to specify an actual reference to the `Registration` object that "owns" them.

You are essentially doing something equivalent to:

```
public class A
{
    public string Hello = "Hello";

    public class B
    {
        //Hello of what A?
        public void SayHello() { 
            Console.Write(Hello); } //Error  
    }
}
```

Which is obviously wrong. What you need to do is:

```
public class B
{
    //Specify what specific A's Hello you want.
    public void SayHello(/*A a*/) {
        Console.Write(a.Hello); }   
}
```

`a` can be a local, a field, a method argument, a property, etc., but it needs to be a variable pointing to a concrete `A` object (or a null reference in which case your code will compile but fail in runtime).

In order to fully understand the error message you are getting, consider the case where `Hello` is static:

```
public class A
{
    public static string Hello = "Hello";

    public class B
    {
        public void SayHello() { 
            Console.Write(Hello); }  
    }
}
```

Now this code will compile just fine because the field `Hello` is now "owned" by the type `A` itself and not by concrete instances of `A`; there is only one `Hello` for all `A`s (this is a pretty informal description of what a static field really is but it should get a reasonably correct mental picture across).

Ok, enough chit chat, how do you solve this? Well without knowing too much of your code, a reasonable way is telling your concrete `CLocation` instance what concrete `Registration` owns it via a constructor:

```
public Registration()
{
    WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
    InitializeComponent();
    CLocation myLocation = new CLocation(this);
    myLocation.GetLocationEvent();
}

public class CLocation
{
     private readonly Registration registrationWindow;

     public CLocation(Registration registrationWindow) {
         this.registrationWindow = registrationWindow; }

     //...

    public void PrintPosition(double Latitude, double Longitude)
    {
        //...
        registrationWindow.tbXCoords.Text = (Latitude.ToString());
        registrationWindow.tbYCoords.Text = (Longitude.ToString());
    }
}
```

Now this might be an overkill if you only need the reference inside your `PrintPosition` method. In that case you can consider specifying the concrete window instance as an argument:

```
public void PrintPosition(Registration registrationWindow,
                          double Latitude, 
                          double Longitude)
{
    //...
    registrationWindow.tbXCoords.Text = (Latitude.ToString());
    registrationWindow.tbYCoords.Text = (Longitude.ToString());
}
```

Again, you should know what fits better in your specific scenario.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you both very much for the answers you provided and the quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why did you put "GeoLocation" code in the different class. But you can fix it like this using the events:

```
public partial class Registration: Window
{
    public Registration()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        InitializeComponent();
        CLocation myLocation = new CLocation();
        myLocation.OnPositionChanged += new EventHandler<PositionEventArgs>(myLocation_OnPositionChanged);
        myLocation.GetLocationEvent();

    }

    private void myLocation_OnPositionChanged(object sender, PositionEventArgs e)
    {
        tbXCoords.Text = (e.Latitude.ToString());
        tbYCoords.Text = (e.Longitude.ToString());
    }

    public class CLocation
    {
        public EventHandler<PositionEventArgs> OnPositionChanged;
        GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher;

        public void GetLocationEvent()
        {
            watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
            watcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(watcher_PositionChanged);
            bool started = this.watcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
            if (!started)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("GeoCoordinateWatcher timed out on start.");
            }
        }

        public void watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
        {
            OnPositionChanged?.Invoke(this, new PositionEventArgs() { Latitude = e.Position.Location.Latitude, Longitude = e.Position.Location.Longitude });
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the PostionEventArgs class:

```
public class PositionEventArgs
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```